# Module not found Error while running flask

Tags: python, flask

My application runs fine by itself. But when I run it via flask - It gives me Module not found Error. My project is set up as follows

```
── myproject
    ├── mypackage
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── utils.py
    └── main.py
    ├── app.py (flask app)
```

Import statement  for my main.py is as follows:

```
from myproject.mypackage.utils  import func
```

Following is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
import main  

@app.route('/)
def run_job():    
    return main.do_something()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

I get error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named myproject
```

Comment: How would Python know where to find that?  it doesn't know your directory structure.  I suggest you do `sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(__file__)+'/..')`, and then `from mypackage.utils import func`.

Comment: what about `from .myproject.mypackage.utils  import func` with a preceding dot?

Answer (score 0):

### Relative imports

The syntax of a relative import depends on the current location as well as the location of the module, package, or object to be imported.

Relative imports make use of dot notation to specify location.

**A single dot means that the module or package referenced is in the same directory as the current location.** Two dots mean that it is in the parent directory of the current location

### So in your case

You should use one dot to access the package in your import

```
from .mypackage.utils  import func
```

Comment: It gives me error : attemped relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Try .mypackage.utils  import func

Answer (score 0):

You said

```
Import statement for my main.py is as follows:

from myproject.mypackage.utils  import func
```

If you mean that within main.py, you have the command - `from myproject.mypackage.utils  import func`, then you should change it to

`from mypackage.utils  import func`